# overridePendingTransition does not work in switch case

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using this code into a switch case. When I start the new activity I want to see a transition animation

```
case 0:
     intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.yea);
     break;
```

Don't work. I don't see animation. With this code works (not in switch case)

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.yea);
```

Comment: Post code with full switch case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

suppose current activity name is `MainActivity.java` then replace 
`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.yea);` with `MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.yea);`

hope this helps you.